# Bootstrap modal won't show up after I called ajax to get modal's element and append to div

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I try to call $.ajax to get my bootstrap modal's html text. Something like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...,
    success: function(data){
                 $("#modal_div").html(data.html);
                 $("#myModal").modal("show");
             }
    });
```

And I have already included bootstrap.min.js in my base html. Btw, I also tried to use a button included in "data.html" to toggle modal, however, I could only see button appended after #modal_div, but couldn't make modal to show up after clicking on the button.

Thank you for your help in advance :)

Comment: have you tried using $("#modal_div").load(url) ???

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way to work around.
If any code are working on newly appended element, put codes inside $(document).ready.

For example (according to my question)

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...,
    success: function(data){
                 $("#modal_div").html(data.html);
                 $(document).ready(function(){
                     $("#myModal").modal("show");
                 }
             }
    });
```

Comment: This is not a solution that is ever suggested to use.